# SetPixelFormat returns 0 Errorcode 3221684230 (C0070006)

Tags: c++, opengl

I try to create an openGL context.
If I start it on an Radeon GPU, it works fine... but on every nvidia Card I tested it, it crashes.

```
m_hWindowHandleToDevice = GetDC(hWnd);

m_PixelFormat = {
    sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),
    1,
    PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,    //Flags
    PFD_TYPE_RGBA,              //The kind of framebuffer. RGBA or palette.
    32,                         //Colordepth of the framebuffer.
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    24,                         //Number of bits for the depthbuffer
    8,                          //Number of bits for the stencilbuffer
    0,                          //Number of Aux buffers in the framebuffer.
    PFD_MAIN_PLANE,
    0,
    0, 0, 0
};

int PixelFormatHandle = ChoosePixelFormat(m_hWindowHandleToDevice, &m_PixelFormat);
BOOL bPixelFormatOK = SetPixelFormat(m_hWindowHandleToDevice, PixelFormatHandle, &m_PixelFormat);
DWORD nLastError = GetLastError();
m_hOpenGLContext = wglCreateContext(m_hWindowHandleToDevice);
nLastError = GetLastError();
```

The variables are:

> ```
> PixelFormatHandle = 9
>
> bPixelFormatOK = 0
>
> nLastError (first time) = 3221684230 
>
> nLastError (at the end) = 2000   //ERROR_INVALID_PIXEL_FORMAT
>
> m_hOpenGLContext = 0
>
> m_hWindowHandleToDevice = 670115fb //so it is set...
> ```

All drivers are updated and I am using:

> ```
> NVIDIA NVS 3100M / not working
>
> NVIDIA gtx 780 / not working
>
> AMD Radeon R7 M370 / is working
>
> Intel(R) HD Graphics 530 / is working
> ```

thank you in advance

Thomas

Comment: I also tested different options (16bit depthbuffer 24bit Colordepth etc...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSDN says the the `cColorBits` is without alpha (though I have seen 32 often there)...

The `SetPixelFormat()` fails (with a FALSE). And it goes down from there. Examine the `Chosen` `PixelFormat` with `DescribePixelFormat`, to make sure you got something sane.

You can only set `Pixel Format` once. Make sure you do.
Where do you call all this? Safest place is in WM_CREATE handler, I think.

Try this legendary old thing: [Nehe OpenGL Window](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/creating_an_opengl_window_%28win32%29/13001/) (there are sources at end).
It would sure be odd if even that doesn't work. Or you know: do not try to be too smart and use GLFW or similar.